# APACH POI parsing HTML with JSOUP

Tags: apache, apache-poi, jsoup, cpu-word

Parsing an HTML text constaining   <font> tags does not reset the size and family font after </font>

My code works pretty well except after </font>.

Before <font size=9> blablabla..  the text size was 11. I was expecting that after </font> the text size was reset to 11, but it still  remains at  9. Same thing for the font family.

Certainly I have misunderstood how to use jsoup. I'd better use CSS, but I don't know how to do.

Thanks for help.

```
package test;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.UnderlinePatterns;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.VerticalAlign;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.select.NodeTraversor;
import org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblLayoutType;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblLayoutType;

public class ReadHtml 
{
    protected static java.util.Vector<String> contenu = null;
    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor = null;

   class WStyle
   {
      protected  String  police     =   "Times New Roman";
      protected  int     taille     =   11;
      protected  Color   couleur    =   Color.black;
      protected  boolean gras       =   false;
      protected  boolean italique   =   false;

      public WStyle() // constructeur
      {
          super();
      }

      protected String getPolice()      {return  police;}
      protected int getTaille()         {return  taille;}
      protected Color getCouleur()      {return  couleur;}
      protected boolean getGras()       {return  gras;}  
      protected boolean getItalique()   {return  italique;} 

      protected void    setPolice(String p)     {police=p;}
      protected void    setTaille(int t)        {taille=t;}
      protected void    setCouleur(Color c)     {couleur=c;}
      protected void    setGras(boolean g)      {gras=g;}  
      protected void    setItalique(boolean i)  {italique=i;} 
   }

    public ReadHtml()
    {
        super();
        contenu =  new java.util.Vector<String>();
        createWordFile();

    }



    private  XWPFParagraph getTableParagraph(XWPFTableCell  cell,  String html)
    {
            cell.removeParagraph(0);
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setSpacingAfterLines(0);
            paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);

            Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.parse(html);
            Elements htmlParagraphs = htmlDocument.select("p");
            for(Element htmlParagraph : htmlParagraphs) 
            {
                  System.out.println(htmlParagraph);
                  ParagraphNodeVisitor nodeVisitor = new ParagraphNodeVisitor(paragraph);
                  NodeTraversor.traverse(nodeVisitor, htmlParagraph);
            }
            return paragraph;
    }

    private   void createWordFile()
    {
          XWPFParagraph para =  null;
          try
          {
                XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("./", "NewTable.docx"));

                XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
                CTTblLayoutType type = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblLayout();
                type.setType(STTblLayoutType.FIXED);
                table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1670));
                table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(6000));

                String myTexte =    "<html><head</head><body><p><font face=\"Verdana\" size=11>Good Morning</font>  <font size=9 face=\"Times\"> " +
                                    "<i><b>how are you today </b></i></font> Not so bad.<br>Thanks";  


                // first  line
                XWPFTableRow tableRow= table.getRow(0);
                para = getTableParagraph(tableRow.getCell(0),  "<p>Row #1,  Col. #1");
                tableRow .getCell(0).setParagraph(para);
                XWPFTableCell cell = tableRow.createCell(); 
                para = getTableParagraph(cell,  myTexte);  // Row #1,  Col. #2
                tableRow .getCell(1).setParagraph(para);

                // seconde line
                tableRow= table.createRow();
                para = getTableParagraph(tableRow.getCell(0),  "<p>Row #2,  Col. #1");
                tableRow .getCell(0).setParagraph(para);
                para = getTableParagraph(tableRow.getCell(1),  "<p>Row #2,  Col. #2");
                tableRow.getCell(1).setParagraph(para);

                document.write(out);
                document.close();
                out.close();
                System.out.println("NewTable.docx written successully");
          } 
          catch (FileNotFoundException e) {System.out.println("File exception --> "  + e.toString()); } 
          catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("I/O exception --> "  + e.toString()); }  
          catch (Exception e)  {System.out.println("Other exception --> "  + e.toString()); } 
    } 

    public class ParagraphNodeVisitor implements NodeVisitor 
    {
          String nodeName;
          String fontFace;
          String fontType;
          boolean needNewRun;
          boolean isItalic;
          boolean isBold;
          boolean isUnderlined;
          int fontSize;
          String fontColor;
          VerticalAlign align = VerticalAlign.BASELINE ;
          XWPFParagraph paragraph;
          XWPFRun run;

          ParagraphNodeVisitor(XWPFParagraph paragraph) 
          {
               this.paragraph = paragraph;
               this.run = paragraph.createRun();
               this.nodeName = "";
               this.needNewRun = false;
               this.isItalic = false;
               this.isBold = false;
               this.isUnderlined = false;
               this.fontSize = 11;
               this.fontColor = "000000";
               this.fontFace="Times";
          }

          @Override
          public void head(Node node, int depth) 
          {
              nodeName = node.nodeName();
              needNewRun = false;
              if ("#text".equals(nodeName)) 
              {
                  run.setText(((TextNode)node).text());
                  needNewRun = true; //after setting the text in the run a new run is needed
              } 
              else if ("i".equals(nodeName)) {isItalic = true;} 
              else if ("b".equals(nodeName)) {isBold = true;} 
              else if ("sup".equals(nodeName)){align = VerticalAlign.SUPERSCRIPT ;} 
              else if ("u".equals(nodeName)) {isUnderlined = true;} 
              else if ("br".equals(nodeName)) {run.addBreak();} 
              else if ("p".equals(nodeName)) {run.addBreak();} 
              else if ("font".equals(nodeName)) 
              {
                  fontColor = (!"".equals(node.attr("color")))?node.attr("color").substring(1):"000000";
                  fontSize = (!"".equals(node.attr("size")))?Integer.parseInt(node.attr("size")):11;
                  fontFace = (!"".equals(node.attr("face")))?node.attr("face"):"Times";
              } 
              if (needNewRun) run = paragraph.createRun();
              needNewRun = false;
              run.setItalic(isItalic);
              run.setBold(isBold);
              if (isUnderlined) run.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE); 
              else run.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.NONE);
              run.setColor(fontColor); 
              run.setFontSize(fontSize);
              run.setFontFamily(fontFace);
              run.setSubscript(align);
          }

          @Override
          public void tail(Node node, int depth) 
          {

              nodeName = node.nodeName();
              System.out.println("Node=" + nodeName);
              if ("i".equals(nodeName)) {isItalic = false;} 
              else if ("b".equals(nodeName)) {isBold = false;} 
              else if ("u".equals(nodeName)) {isUnderlined = false;} 
              else if ("sup".equals(nodeName)) {align= VerticalAlign.BASELINE ;}
              else if ("font".equals("nodeName")) 
              {
                  fontColor = "000000";
                  fontSize = 11;
                  fontFace="Times";
                  System.out.println("Family=" + fontFace + "   Taille=" + fontSize);
              }

              if (needNewRun) run = paragraph.createRun();
               needNewRun = false;
               run.setItalic(isItalic);
               run.setBold(isBold);
               if (isUnderlined) run.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE); else run.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.NONE);
               run.setColor(fontColor); 
               run.setFontSize(fontSize);

               run.setFontFamily(fontFace);
               run.setSubscript(align);
          }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
              new ReadHtml() ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: The code you are using here is pretty much the code I have provided in answer to your last Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268485/how-to-set-define-different-styles-for-the-same-paragraph. So I suspect that answer has answered your question? If so please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. And it is question of kindly and fairness at least to mention that you are not the originally author of main parts of the code you are showing now in that question.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the following line in your `tail` method, from

```
else if ("font".equals("nodeName"))
```

to

```
else if ("font".equals(nodeName))
```

You've compared two string literals instead of compare a string literal to the variable. Because of the typo the condition is always `false`, therefore `fontSize` is never reseted.