# Not able to add bullet points and styles like bold and italic for some portion of a line using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, jsoup

I'm reading one string in that some `li` tags have spans with styles so I'm trying to add styles for a particular word in the `li` tag (not for the whole line), but for every styles change it is going for new bullet point instead of appending to the same `li`,

String:

```
"<p><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Title</span></p> <ul> <li> <span style=\"font-weight: bold;\"> </span><span>Laser cutting of sheet </span><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">metal</span><span> generates a continuous heat source which can led to high levels of thermal stress </span> </li> <li><span>Thermal Stress can deform the material at the micron level and the slightest deformation reduces the effectiveness of the sheet metal components</span></li> <br /> </ul> <p><span> </span><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Mass Level Production</span></p> <ul> <li><span>Laser cutting cannot produce more component more than one part at a time</span></li> <li><span>When production is required at a lower level , laser cutting may be apt but inefficient for mass level production</span></li> </ul> <p><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Metal etching with aluminum</span></p> <p><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\"> </span></p> <ul> <li><span>Aluminum is a reflective material that is reactive to heat in the manufacturing process and therefore, makes it less suitable for laser cutting and wire EDM processes</span></li> <li> <span>As the use of aluminum is growing in many industries, there is a requirement for a suitable manufacturing process for thin </span><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">aluminum</span><span>components</span> </li> </ul>"
```

Can anyone help me, like where I'm doing the mistake?
Code:

```
public static void advancedUlLiConvert(XSLFTextShape textShape, String str) {
    System.out.println("Recived String: "+str);
        
    Document doc = null;
        
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
            
        Element element = doc.body();
        Elements lstElements = element.children();
        System.out.println("bodyChildEle : " +lstElements);
            
        for (Element ele: lstElements) {
            if (ele.tagName() == "p") {
                System.out.println("para" + ele);
                String para = ele.children().toString();

                System.out.println("String para" + para);
                //if any <p> tags are there then I'm calling this method to take care of that which is working fine,
                addAllStyledText(textShape,para, false);
            }
            //I'm facing problems in these below part
            if (ele.tagName() == "ul") {
                Elements lstLi = ele.children();
                System.out.println("lstsi" + lstLi);
                    
                for (Element li: lstLi) {
                    Elements spans = li.children();

                    XSLFTextParagraph paragraph = textShape.addNewTextParagraph();
                    paragraph.setBullet(true);
                    XSLFTextRun textRun = paragraph.addNewTextRun();
                        
                    System.out.println("allspans: " + spans);
                        
                    for (Element span: spans) {
                        System.out.println("loopspan" + span);
                            
                        if (!(span.hasText())) {
                            span.remove();
                            System.out.println("Removed Element: "+ span);
                        } else if (span.hasAttr("style")) {
                            System.out.println("Styled Span: " + span);
                            String strSpan = span.toString();
                            boolean isBold = false;
                            boolean isItalic = false;
                            boolean isUnderline = false;
                            boolean isLineThrough = false;
                                
                            if (strSpan.contains(": bold;"))
                                isBold = true;
                                
                            if (strSpan.contains(": italic;"))
                                isItalic = true;
                                
                            if (strSpan.contains(": underline;"))
                                isUnderline = true;
                                
                            if (strSpan.contains(": line-through;"))
                                isLineThrough = true;
                                
                            String text = span.text();
                            textRun = textShape.appendText(text+" ", false);
                                
                            if (isBold) {
                                textRun.setBold(true);
                                //textRun.setFontColor(rgb);
                            }
                            if (isItalic) {
                                textRun.setItalic(true);
                            }
                            if (isUnderline) {
                                textRun.setUnderlined(true);
                            }
                            if (isLineThrough) {
                                textRun.setStrikethrough(true);
                            }
                            //textRun.setText(text);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Span without Style: " + span);
                            String text = span.text();
                            //if I make this as false than whole code braking not sure why
                            textRun = textShape.appendText(text + " ", true);
                            //textRun.setText(text);
                            //paragraph.setBullet(false);
                            //paragraph.setBullet(false);
                            //paragraph.addNewTextRun().setText(text);
                        }

                        XSLFTextRun dummyTextRun = textShape.appendText("", false);
                        dummyTextRun.setBold(false);
                        dummyTextRun.setItalic(false);
                        dummyTextRun.setUnderlined(false);
                        dummyTextRun.setStrikethrough(false);
                    }
                    paragraph.setBullet(false);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception in advancedUlLiConvert: " , e);
    }
}
```

Code Output:
[image]

My expectation :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To program a HTML to XSLFTextParagraph converter, which considers all the ugly possibilities of that HTML tag-soup, would lead to program a whole library. HTML is a mess, nothing else. No real rules, all free interpretable by browsers.

JSoup is a helper but not the complete solution. I have adopted my attempt of [How to set define different styles for the same paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268485/how-to-set-define-different-styles-for-the-same-paragraph/54275245#54275245) to `XSLF`. As told there it uses  `NodeTraversor` and `NodeVisitor` of JSoup. I have extended this to consider inline-CSS using `style` attributes in `SPAN` elements. Also I have extended it to consider `LI` elements in `UL` elements as bulleted paragraphs.

Complete example converting your given HTML-String:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor;
import org.jsoup.select.NodeTraversor;

public class HTMLtoPPTX {

 private XMLSlideShow slideShow;

 public HTMLtoPPTX(String html, String pptxPath) throws Exception {

  this.slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();
  XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();
  XSLFTextShape textShape = slide.createAutoShape();
  java.awt.Rectangle rect = new java.awt.Rectangle(100, 100, 500, 400);
  textShape.setAnchor(rect.getBounds2D());
  textShape.setShapeType(ShapeType.RECT);

  XSLFTextParagraph paragraph = null;
  Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.parse(html);
  Elements htmlElements = htmlDocument.select("p:not(li *), ul li:not(li *)");
  for(Element htmlElement : htmlElements) {

System.out.println(htmlElement);

   paragraph = textShape.addNewTextParagraph();
   createParagraphFromHTML(paragraph, htmlElement);
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pptxPath);
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
  slideShow.close();

 }

 void createParagraphFromHTML(XSLFTextParagraph paragraph, Element htmlElement) {

  ParagraphNodeVisitor nodeVisitor = new ParagraphNodeVisitor(paragraph);
  NodeTraversor.traverse(nodeVisitor, htmlElement);

 }

 private class ParagraphNodeVisitor implements NodeVisitor {

  String nodeName;
  boolean isItalic;
  boolean isBold;
  boolean isUnderlined;
  double fontSize;
  java.awt.Color fontColor;
  XSLFTextParagraph paragraph;
  XSLFTextRun run;
  boolean spanStyleSetBold;
  boolean spanStyleSetItalic;
  boolean spanStyleSetUnderlined;
  boolean spanStyleSetFontColor;
  boolean spanStyleSetFontSize;

  ParagraphNodeVisitor(XSLFTextParagraph paragraph) {
   this.paragraph = paragraph;
   this.run = paragraph.addNewTextRun(); this.run.setText("");
   this.nodeName = "";
   this.isItalic = false;
   this.isBold = false;
   this.isUnderlined = false;
   this.fontSize = 11d;
   this.fontColor = java.awt.Color.BLACK;
   this.spanStyleSetBold = false;
   this.spanStyleSetItalic = false;
   this.spanStyleSetUnderlined = false;
   this.spanStyleSetFontColor = false;
   this.spanStyleSetFontSize = false;

  }

  @Override
  public void head(Node node, int depth) {
   nodeName = node.nodeName();

System.out.println("Start "+nodeName+": " + node);

   if ("#text".equals(nodeName)) {
    run.setText(((TextNode)node).text​());
   } else if ("i".equals(nodeName)) {
    isItalic = true;
   } else if ("b".equals(nodeName)) {
    isBold = true;
   } else if ("u".equals(nodeName)) {
    isUnderlined = true;
   } else if ("br".equals(nodeName)) {
    run = run.getParagraph().addLineBreak();
   } else if ("font".equals(nodeName)) {
    String rgbS = (!"".equals(node.attr("color")))?node.attr("color"):"#000000";
    fontColor = new java.awt.Color(
     Integer.valueOf(rgbS.substring(1, 3), 16),
     Integer.valueOf(rgbS.substring(3, 5), 16),
     Integer.valueOf(rgbS.substring(5, 7), 16)
    );
    fontSize = (!"".equals(node.attr("size")))?Double.parseDouble(node.attr("size")):11d;
   } else if ("li".equals(nodeName)) {
    paragraph.setBullet(true); 
   } else if ("span".equals(nodeName)) {
    String style = node.attr("style");
    if (style.matches(".*\\bfont-weight:\\s*bold\\s*;.*")) {
     isBold = true;
     spanStyleSetBold = true;
    }
    if (style.matches(".*\\bfont-style:\\s*italic\\s*;.*")) {
     isItalic = true;
     spanStyleSetItalic = true;
    }
    if (style.matches(".*\\btext-decoration:\\s*underline\\s*;.*")) {
     isUnderlined = true;
     spanStyleSetUnderlined = true;
    }
    //if (style.matches(".*\\bcolor:\\s*(#[0-9a-fA-F]+)\\s*;.*")) { 
    // ToDo      
    //}
    //if (style.matches(".*\\bfont-size:\\s*(#[0-9]+)\\s*;.*")) { 
    // ToDo      
    //}  
   }
   
   run.setItalic(isItalic);
   run.setBold(isBold);
   if (isUnderlined) run.setUnderlined(true); else run.setUnderlined(false);
   run.setFontColor(fontColor); run.setFontSize(fontSize);
  }

  @Override
  public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
   nodeName = node.nodeName();

System.out.println("End "+nodeName);

   if ("#text".equals(nodeName)) {
    run = paragraph.addNewTextRun(); run.setText(""); //after setting the text in the run a new run is needed
   } else if ("i".equals(nodeName)) {
    isItalic = false;
   } else if ("b".equals(nodeName)) {
    isBold = false;
   } else if ("u".equals(nodeName)) {
    isUnderlined = false;
   } else if ("br".equals(nodeName)) {
    run = paragraph.addNewTextRun(); run.setText(""); //after setting a break a new run is needed
   } else if ("font".equals(nodeName)) {
    fontColor = java.awt.Color.BLACK;
    fontSize = 11d;
   } else if ("li".equals(nodeName)) {
    // ToDo
   } else if ("span".equals(nodeName)) {
    if (spanStyleSetItalic) isItalic = false;
    if (spanStyleSetBold) isBold = false;
    if (spanStyleSetUnderlined) isUnderlined = false;
    //if (spanStyleSetFontColor) fontColor = java.awt.Color.BLACK; //ToDo
    //if (spanStyleSetFontSize) fontSize = 11d; //ToDo
    run = paragraph.addNewTextRun(); run.setText(""); //after a span a new run is needed
   }
   run.setItalic(isItalic);
   run.setBold(isBold);
   if (isUnderlined) run.setUnderlined(true); else run.setUnderlined(false);
   run.setFontColor(fontColor); run.setFontSize(fontSize);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String html = 
   "<p><font size='32' color='#0000FF'><b>First paragraph.</font></b><br/>Just like a heading</p>"
  +"<p>This is my text <i>which now is in italic <b>but also in bold</b> depending on its <u>importance</u></i>.<br/>Now a <b><i><u>new</u></i></b> line starts <i>within <b>the same</b> paragraph</i>.</p>"
  +"<p><b>Last <u>paragraph <i>comes</u> here</b> finally</i>.</p>"
  +"<p>But yet <u><i><b>another</i></u></b> paragraph having <i><font size='22' color='#FF0000'>special <u>font</u> settings</font></i>. Now default font again.</p>"
  +"<p />"
  ;

  //html += 
  html = 
   "<p><span style=\"font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline; \">Title</span></p>"
  +"<ul> <li> <span style=\"font-weight: bold;\"> </span><span>Laser cutting of sheet </span><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">metal</span><span> generates a continuous heat source which can led to high levels of thermal stress </span> </li> <li><span>Thermal Stress can deform the material at the micron level and the slightest deformation reduces the effectiveness of the sheet metal components</span></li> <br /> </ul>"
  +"<p><span> </span><span style=\"font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;\">Mass Level Production</span></p>"
  +"<ul> <li><span>Laser cutting cannot produce more component more than one part at a time</span></li> <li><span>When production is required at a lower level , laser cutting may be apt but inefficient for mass level production</span></li> </ul>"
  +"<p><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Metal etching with aluminum</span></p>"
  +"<p><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\"> </span></p>"
  +"<ul> <li><span>Aluminum is a reflective material that is reactive to heat in the manufacturing process and therefore, makes it less suitable for laser cutting and wire EDM processes</span></li> <li> <span>As the use of aluminum is growing in many industries, there is a requirement for a suitable manufacturing process for thin </span><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">aluminum</span><span>components</span> </li> </ul>"
  ;
  
  HTMLtoPPTX htmlToPPTX = new HTMLtoPPTX(html, "./CreatePowerPointTextFromHTML.pptx");

 }
}
```

Again: Disclaimer: This is a working draft showing the principle. Neither it is fully ready nor it is code ready for use in productive environments.