# Is it possible to write html content(formatted) into word document using Apache POI?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using apache poi to create word document where in particular places i need to show html content(like list or bold, italic etc) to word document. I didn't find such kind of information into apache POI where i can show similar style into word document.

Expecting same style like html content into word document using apache POI

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268485/how-to-set-define-different-styles-for-the-same-paragraph/54275245#54275245

Comment: I thought apache POI itself has some built-in functionality to handle it. I didn't want another library to handle it.

Comment: "I thought apache POI itself has some built-in functionality to handle it.": No, it has not.